# How to customize the webform field validation message?

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

there is a huge issue where when a Phone number field is validated on a webform, we get the following error message:

North American Phone numbers should only contain numbers and + and - and ( and ) and spaces and be like 999-999-9999. Please enter a valid ten-digit phone number with optional extension.

In reality we need an ability to customize this and we were looking into the hook_form_alter, but we hit a snag and cannot find ways to modify the error message. How would we be able to modify the validation messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution here is the [String Overrides module](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides).

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Easily replace anything that's passed through t()
> - Locale support,
>     allowing you to override strings in any language
> - Ability to
>     import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the Locale module
> - Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of
>     overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you need
>     a few easy text changes.

For your case, you can override the Phone module's [default error message](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/phone/tree/include/phone.ca.inc?h=7.x-1.0-beta1#n10). By placing this string in this string:

> "%value" is not a valid North American phone number
> North American
>   Phone numbers should only contain numbers and + and - and ( and ) and
>   spaces and be like 999-999-9999. Please enter a valid ten-digit phone
>   number with optional extension.

And substituting whatever you need it to display.

Comment: One solution we found is to patch the phone module as we found the validation message coming from that module.